# Accordion menu in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am playing with a Accordion Menu plugin, [specifically example 3](http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-menu-redux/#): Non-accordion (standard expandable menu).

I am basically trying to use the example 3 option of this accordion menu by where I have 5 menu options, where two out of the five have sub-menus and the other three don't - they are just direct calls to a page.

Example:

Menu A
Menu B
     Sub-Menu B1
     Sub-Menu B2
Menu C
Menu D
     Sub-Menu D1
     Sub-Menu D2
     Sub-Menu D3
     Sub-Menu D4
Menu E

Everything works fine but what I am after and unsure how to incorporate into the code is that if initially the whole menu is collapsed and I click on Menu B, which slides down sub-menu B content for this menu, what I am after is that as soon as I click on another menu option, say Menu A or even the other sub-menu option D, if there is an existing accordion menu expanded, I would like to see Menu B collapse when I click on either Menu A (no sub-menu) or Menu D (with sub-menu).

How can I incorporate this functionality into this plugin, for example 3 from this website?

Comment: I just looked at the link you provided, example #4 looks like it does exactly what you need.  You should check that site one more time, it looks like you just need to add 2 CSS classes to get the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Zachary - I did look at example #4 but this seems to open the accordion menu with the first available sub-menus, which is not what I'm after and unsure how to modify this so that the expandfirst class is not utilized. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks Zachary - took your lead and only needed to create just one class for the li's that didn't have a ul. Code I used if anybody might be interested is:   if($(this).hasClass('nosub')) {
    $('#' + parent + ' ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
    $("ul.menu li ul li a").removeClass("currentSubMenu");
   }

Answer (score 1):

From the source at the bottom of the page:

```
[snip]

if($('#' + parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
    return false;
}
...
```

Basically, this line trumps the others: if your accordion has the `noaccordion` class, it will not automatically close any open elements when you click another.

Removing `noaccordion` from your `ul`'s markup would make it behave like the other examples, collapsing any open nodes when you click a different node.

Comment: hi @ajm - just tried what you said and removed the class noaccordion, ran the page, click on the menu with a submenu and then clicked on one without a submenu and unfortunately, did not collapse my original submenu selection - kept it open even though I clicked away on another menu option.